# What is the difference between 比如 and 例如

Tags: meaning, usage, synonyms

I know both can mean "for example/such as/for instance". They are most likely synonyms but even synonyms have slight subtle differences in precise meaning and usage. 
I know that 例 can be used alone: (**例句** -- *example sentence*; **例语** -- *example word/phrase*) and 比 cannot (比句 and 比语 don't exactly make much sense).
What I don't know are the specific semantic differences between 例如 and 比如.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `比如` is more colloquial, `例如` is more formal.

Comment: It helps me to break the words apart: 比 means "compare", 例 means "example", 如 means "with; as; comply with". So, one way of translating 比如 is "compare (that) with ..." and 例如 is "(here is something) as an example ...".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`比如` used for `similar but have different things`;

`例如` used for `many of the same things, and take a typical example, using the example to illustrate the general of many things`

Also, `比如` may not exist, but `例如` is must really exist.

> 比如和例如最重要的区别在“比”“例”的不同上。两词共有的“如”都是“象”的意思。但是，“比如”是用两个有些相似但是根本不同事物间的形容。例如说，“说话就比如是骑自行车样，要练习。”这里就不能用“例如”。“例如”是在说明很多相同的事物时，从中拿出一个典型的例子，用这个例子来说明众多的一般的事物。例如：“大家都很无私，例如小李就捐了一万块。”这里用比如好像可以，但是准确的应该是“例如”。

See [here](http://wenku.baidu.com/view/941f119c9ec3d5bbfd0a7471.html)